# JavaFx and Concurrency

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, javafx

I've got the following code:

The Controller.class of my project:

```
    private Task<ObservableList<Payment>> allEntrieTask= new Task<ObservableList<Payment>>(){
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected ObservableList<Payment> call() throws Exception {
            List<Payment> list = (List<Payment>) sqlExecutor.listAllEntries(Payment.class);
            ObservableList<Payment> payments = (ObservableList<Payment>) FXCollections.observableList(list);
            FXCollections.sort(payments);
            return payments;
        }

    };

    private Task<ObservableList<Payment>> revenueEntrieTask= new Task<ObservableList<Payment>>(){
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected ObservableList<Payment> call() throws Exception {
            List<Payment> list = (List<Payment>) sqlExecutor.listEntries(Payment.class, Restrictions.gt("payment", 0.0));
            ObservableList<Payment> payments = FXCollections.observableList(list);
            FXCollections.sort(payments);
            return payments;
        }

    };

    private Task<ObservableList<Payment>> outputsEntrieTask= new Task<ObservableList<Payment>>(){
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected ObservableList<Payment> call() throws Exception {
            List<Payment> list = (List<Payment>) sqlExecutor.listEntries(Payment.class, Restrictions.lt("payment", 0.0));
            ObservableList<Payment> payments = FXCollections.observableList(list);
            FXCollections.sort(payments);
            return payments;
        }

    };
public void onTreeAction(MouseEvent e){
        if(e.getClickCount() == 2){
            String chosenItem = tree.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().getValue(); //Ausgewähltes Item
            if(chosenItem.equals("Alle Zahlungen")){
                listAllPayments();
                actualTable = "Alle Zahlungen";
            }else if(chosenItem.equals("Einzahlungen")){
                listAllRevenues();
                actualTable = "Einzahlungen";
            }else if(chosenItem.equals("Auszahlungen")){
                listAllOutputs();
                actualTable = "Auszahlungen";
            }
        }
    }

    private void listAllPayments(){
        Thread t = new Thread(allEntrieTask);
        t.setDaemon(true);
        t.start();
        allEntrieTask.setOnSucceeded(event -> table.setItems(allEntrieTask.getValue()));
    }

    private void listAllRevenues(){
        Thread t = new Thread(revenueEntrieTask);
        t.setDaemon(true);
        t.start();
        revenueEntrieTask.setOnSucceeded(event -> table.setItems(revenueEntrieTask.getValue()));
    }

    private void listAllOutputs(){
        Thread t = new Thread(outputsEntrieTask);
        t.setDaemon(true);
        t.start();
        outputsEntrieTask.setOnSucceeded(event -> table.setItems(outputsEntrieTask.getValue()));
    }
```

Is this the way how it should look like when I use concurrency in java?I've putted ,all the code which may need some time to act, inside a task which starts when the specified `Item` is selected in the `TreeView`. Another question I've got,I got this code:

```
   private void listAllPayments(){
    Thread t = new Thread(allEntrieTask);
    t.setDaemon(true);
    t.start();
    allEntrieTask.setOnSucceeded(event -> table.setItems(allEntrieTask.getValue()));
}
```

This action: `allEntrieTask.setOnSucceeded(event -> table.setItems(allEntrieTask.getValue()));` is running on the FXApplicationThread right?Or must I do somegthing like `Platform.runLater(//do some stuff)`. My project works fine wihtout any error or info

Comment: It probably doesn't work if you double-click on the same item twice, right?

Comment: No, it works when I double click the same item twice

Comment: Weird: it shouldn't. From the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html): "As with FutureTask, a Task is a one-shot class and cannot be reused." Thus you should really create a new Task instance each time you want to run it, instead of reusing the same instance. The other problem is that in `listAllPayments()` you should call `setOnSucceeded(...)` before you call `t.start()`. Since things are running in different threads you have no guarantee that the task doesn't finish before `setOnSucceeded(...)` is called (the table update wouldn't happen)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your solution :)

Comment: Should I use a own class for every Task? Or is it ok, to use an inner class?